# Loading an event on url change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, accordion

How do you make a page loads to certain section and open an accordion.

For example, I have a page with bunch of accordions listed vertically and yes, I am aware of the option to give them id's and in url page#accordion1 will open it and scroll exactly there. So, what sort of JS I am missing here so that #accordion1 loads clicked automatically on certain url path?

Comment: Would be easier if you have posted your code.

Comment: Did you find the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Yes I did, code below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this worked... so if the url targets any element with an id, it'll scroll to it and do things. In this case, it'll open the accordion (add and remove a class)

```
(function($){
$(window).load(function(){
var et_hash = window.location.hash;
if(window.location.hash) {
$( '.et_pb_toggle' + et_hash )
.removeClass('et_pb_toggle_close')
.addClass('et_pb_toggle_open')
}
});
})(jQuery)

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event){ 

    if (window.location.hash) {
        // Start at top of page
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);

        // Prevent default scroll to anchor by hiding the target element
        var db_hash_elem = document.getElementById(window.location.hash.substring(1));
        window.db_location_hash_style = db_hash_elem.style.display;
        db_hash_elem.style.display = 'none';

        // After a short delay, display the element and scroll to it
        jQuery(function($){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(window.location.hash).css('display', window.db_location_hash_style);
                et_pb_smooth_scroll($(window.location.hash), false, 800);
            }, 700);
        });     
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We first need to wait till the whole page is loaded in case your accordion hasn't fully initialised yet.

Then we grab the hash out of the URL so we can check if it matches what we want. Additionally we use a switch statement to check against known values since we can't trust any input.

We locate the relevant accordion by it's ID, which if your code doesn't have you would need to add.

```
// Trigger when the whole document loads
window.onload = function(){
    // Grab the hash out of the URL
    switch(window.location.hash){
        case "#accordion1":
            // Click the relevant item located by its ID
            document.getElementById("accordion1ID").click();
            break;
        case "#accordion2":
            document.getElementById("accordion2ID").click();
            break;
    }
}
```